# Unable to open Anypoint studio because of JDK issue

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I installed JDK 8 and set up environment variables, still Im unable to start Anypoint studio. Please refer below screeshots and advise. I am not allowed to embed images here as I am a beginner, so provided links to screenshots

Error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl8iI.png)

java version:

[java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxf0q.png)

java installation folder (jdk and jre)

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2lYQ.png)

environment variables "JAVA_HOME" & "Path":

[env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84pLd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check for both **javac -version** and **java -version** and if they are showing proper version details then Anypoint studio should get opened..

Answer (score 0):

Open the AnypointStudio.ini and add the following line:

-vm

"Path to your java installation dir"/bin/javaw.exe

For example:

-vm

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/javaw.exe